# My Moq mock isn't being accepted in my method under test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, moq-3

When I create my moq mock and try to pass it into my class constructor I get this message:
Argument type Moq.Mock<...mockIAppCache> is not assingable to paramter type 'IAppCache'.
I included the library and I can find the reference to Mock() ok. Am I missing something here?

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void SomeTestMethod()
    {
        var mockIAppCache = new Mock<IAppCache>();
        var mockISeries = new Mock<ISeries>();

        ReportFR2 report = new ReportFR2(SeriesKey.FR2, mockIAppCache);
        DateTime resolvedDate = report.ResolveDate(mockISeries, DateTime.Now);

        //Assert.AreEqual("something", "something");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to pass the mock like this:

```
ReportFR2 report = new ReportFR2(SeriesKey.FR2, mockIAppCache.Object);
```